# JavaScript Error(Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using javascript in my asp.net project dynamically. But this error occurred:
" Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected".
Here is my code :

```
dropdownlist1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return" + "confirm('Kaydetmek istediğinize emin misiniz')");
```

pop up is not opening. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this, adding a space between return and confirm.
The concatenation isn't really required

```
dropdownlist1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return confirm('Kaydetmek istediğinize emin misiniz')");
```